# Loading dependencies via network

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, resolve

Iam loading all my dependencies from a server, however Iam faceing an Issue with loading 2 specific Dll files.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
return Assembly.Load(dll.bytes);
```

https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl

Iam trying to load
 "SharpGL.SceneGraph.dll"
 "SharpGL.WPF.dll"

Getting a System.TypeLoadException Type: SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl couldnt be loaded

Also Iam loading controls from my own wpf libary just fine. Anyone an idea whats going on ?

Edit1:
The stacktrace just saying that this line caused the exception

```
<wpf:OpenGLControl Name="D3Render" OpenGLDraw="D3Render_OnOpenGLDraw" FrameRate="60" Height="300" Width="300" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
```

The Error

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Der Typ "SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl" in der Assembly "SharpGL, Version=2.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=27fc851303210b27" konnte nicht geladen werden.'
```

Also printing all calls from the resolve Method:

```
SharedObjects.dll
MongoDB.Bson.dll
SharpPcap.dll
PacketDotNet.dll
SharpGL.WPF.dll
```

Edit2:
Added a test to reproduce the issue
https://github.com/KenionX/DependencieTest

Edit3:
For some reason it works on my test Repo... I dont know why but gona figure it out

~Zerray

Comment: Please copy/paste the implementation of `CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve`. Do you taking any measures there? If there are any dependencies of a loaded assembly which cannot be found in your AppDomain and lookup - probing directories, this event handler will be invoked, and you are to find those missing dependencies yourself.

Comment: if the DLLs are non-managed... meaning like C++ you will need to copy them to the hard drive during assembly resolve and then load them from the hard drive...

Comment: also we need to see the complte exception with stack trace

Comment: I looked at the two libraries you mentioned and those libraries have other dependencies... do you have those dependencies in the server as well?

Comment: SharpGL seems to be a managed assembly after all. You can actually see what dependency is missing in the event handler `CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve`. What you need to do is, to get these dependencies (and their dependencies, and their dependencies) too from the server.

Comment: Well there is no missing dependency. Iam adding the full stack.

Comment: What dependenies are missing? And shouldnt the assembly resolver ask for the dependencies?

Comment: The assembly resolver asks for them. Are you loading them in there? It proceeds like this; you try to load an assembly, the run-time calls you if there are any missing dependencies and expect you to provide them. So in the event handler `CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve` you should load the missing assembly and return it. That's why I asked for the source code of your `CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve` event handler in the first place

Comment: So those five dll's you see in the resolver event handler are actually missing. It sometimes does not help if you already have references to these in your project, because of different versions being referenced. You can, however, overcome this by using [Assembly Version Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

Comment: The dlls Iposted are all correct resolved, on the last assembly in the list it crashes and the resolve event doesnt fire after that.

Comment: You mean `SharpGL.WPF.dll` ?

Comment: yes, after returning the SharpGL.WPF.dll it instant crashes on the missing typ

Comment: if you look at the GIT page you posted for SharpGL if you explore the code you will find there are some dlls required to use SharpGL. and if those are not present or if they are C++ dlls you will have to change your code to account for that

Comment: Can you check the framework version of SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl? There is a post talking about reverting back to 4.0 to make this assembly work.

Comment: well, if I put the SharpGL.WPF.dll next to the exe it works fine, so there are no additional depedencie files missing..

Comment: @OguzOzgul I also updated the whole sharpGL libary to the most recent framework and 64 bit, still the same issue :(

Comment: Ok, the exception is not related to loading assemblies, bu is saying that the `SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl` type could not be loaded, which means the static constructor (this class has a static constructor) has failed. I don't know why, but it has just one statement which fails when loaded dynamically: `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(OpenGLControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(OpenGLControl)));`

Comment: I see ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.dll and RibonControlsLibrary.dll in the SharpGL project

Comment: Also I would try to just load the assembly from the server and save it to disk then load it from there just to see if that works

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro yes, that works just fine. If the dll is next to the exe

Comment: @OguzOzgul for some reason it works now on my test project  ..w t f

Comment: @Kenion when Dlls need Security Descriptors they have to be saved to the drive.  I know because I had the problem in a couple of projects in the past.  So what I ended up doing was loading them from the server as the other dlls then saving those on the drive and resolving them from the drive.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro it works fine now, fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue was somewhere else, instead of loading the SharpGL.WPF.dll my server sent me the SharpGL.dll, the string comparison on the server was the issue! Thx to everyone.